# MySQL display table in csv format

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I want to display my database table in csv format without creating a csv file. (Just in my console) Is there any way to do this ? 
Thanks Yannic.

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question. We will help you fix bugs, not just do your work for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using this :

I have a table test :

```
    select  * from test ;
    +----+--------------+-------------+
    | id | md_name      | total_visit |
    +----+--------------+-------------+
    |  1 | Nunu Nugraha |          33 |
    |  2 | Erwin        |          32 |
    |  3 | Tri Sulistyo |          35 |
    |  4 | Risdianto    |          24 |
    |  5 | Erma         |          22 |
    |  6 | Dwi Sabana   |          19 |
    |  7 | Ernayanti    |          26 |
    |  8 | Ali          |          10 |
    |  9 | Partini      |          13 |

+----+--------------+-------------+
```

execute query this  for CSV format :

```
select concat(id,',',md_name,',',total_visit) as csv from test;
-------------------+
| csv               |
+-------------------+
| 1,Nunu Nugraha,33 |
| 2,Erwin,32        |
| 3,Tri Sulistyo,35 |
| 4,Risdianto,24    |
| 5,Erma,22         |
| 6,Dwi Sabana,19   |
| 7,Ernayanti,26    |
| 8,Ali,10          |
| 9,Partini,13      |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

sample tables and output:

```
SELECT * FROM NS2_EMP;

10001   Scott Tiger 1000    40
10002   Frank Naude 500     20

SELECT empno||','||empname||','||sal||','||deptno
FROM ns2_emp;

10001,Scott Tiger,1000,40
10002,Frank Naude,500,20
```